# Create Variable from MySQL Cell Inside Loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, loops, while-loop

I hope that title is sufficient for the contents of this question...

I've patched together a little script from various sources that writes every row in a MySQL database to a separate XML file.  It does what it is supposed to do, however I'm hung up on the naming convention.

I'd like to name the XML file from the 'id' column of the row that is being exported, where `$id`is the name of the file sans extension.

Tried accessing this through xpath to no avail.

How do I access a particular column's data (cell) and assign it to a variable?

```
<?php

$host       = "";
$user       = "";
$pass       = "";
$database   = "";

// Replace by a query that matches your database
$SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM data";

$DB_link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");
mysql_select_db($database, $DB_link) or die ("Could not find or access the database.");
$result = mysql_query ($SQL_query, $DB_link) or die ("Data not found. Your SQL query didn't work... ");

//ROWS
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {    
  $id;
  $XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
  $XML .= "<order>\n";
  $XML .= "\t<item>\n"; 
  $i = 0;
  // cells
  foreach ($row as $cell) {
    // Escaping illegal characters - not tested actually ;)
    $cell = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $cell);
    $col_name = mysql_field_name($result,$i);
    // creates the "<tag>contents</tag>" representing the column
    $XML .= "\t\t<" . $col_name . ">" . $cell . "</" . $col_name . ">\n";
    $i++;
  }
  $XML .= "\t</item>\n";
  $XML .= "</order>\n";

  $handle = fopen($id.'.xml','w+');
  fwrite($handle,$XML);
  fclose($handle); 
 }

?>
```

Comment: You really should be using PHP built in XML functionality instead of building XML manually.

Comment: Thanks - I've rebuilt the whole thing using XMLWriter and got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to spend hours on google and rewrote this using XMLWriter:

```
<?php

$host       = "";
$user       = "";
$pass       = "";
$database   = "";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Could not connect to host.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Could not find or access the database");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Data not found. Your SQL query didn't work...");

//start document

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    //use this variable for filename later
    $name = $row['id'];
    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openMemory();
    $xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $xml->setIndent(true);
    $xml->startElement('order');    
    $xml->startElement('item');

    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        $xml->writeElement($key,$value);
    }

    //$xml->writeElement('id',$row['id']);

    $xml->endElement(); 
    $xml->endElement();



    //close document
    $xml->endDocument();

    file_put_contents($name .'.xml', $xml->outputMemory());
}
?>
```